# Select rows which exists in a foreign table at least N times?

Tags: sql, join

i am having the following issue.

i am doing some "simple" filtering. I am submitting a min-value from 1-100.

Master Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `materials` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `materialNr` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Aliases Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `materialsAliases` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `materialsId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aliasName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `materialStandard` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I want to select all materials from the materials table which have N aliases in the aliases table. Not all materials do have aliases, for those there is no entry in the materialsAliases table. some materials have a lot of aliases which then are placed into the meterialAliases table and is linked from meterialAliases.materialsId to materials.id.

Thats what i tried so far (just ignore the other joins):

```
SELECT 
    materials.`active`, 
    materials.`id`, 
    materials.`materialNr`,
    materialDescriptionsDe.`description`,
    materialDescriptionsEn.`description`,
FROM `materials`

LEFT JOIN materialDescriptionsDe
ON `materials`.id=materialDescriptionsDe.`materialsId`

LEFT JOIN materialDescriptionsEn
ON `materials`.id=materialDescriptionsEn.`materialsId`

LEFT JOIN materialsAliases
ON `materials`.id=materialsAliases.`materialsId`

WHERE `materialNr` LIKE ? 

ORDER BY materials.`id` DESC

LIMIT 25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT:

```
SELECT materials.id, materials.materialNr
FROM materials
LEFT JOIN materialsAliases ON materials.id = materialsAliases.materialsId
WHERE materialNr LIKE ? 
GROUP BY materials.id, materials.materialNr
HAVING COUNT(materialsAliases.id) >= ? -- this is your N
ORDER BY materials.id DESC
```

You can remove `materials.materialNr` from the select and group by clause to end up with a query that simply returns `materials.id`. You can then feed the result into a more complex query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand your purpose tbh, I wish you put "expected output" in your question with some sample data. I still believe using INNER join like below will help you to see the only such materials having at least one alias:

```
SELECT 
    materials.active, 
    materials.id, 
    materials.materialNr,
    materialDescriptionsDe.description,
    materialDescriptionsEn.description,
FROM materials m
INNER JOIN materialsAliases ma ON m.id=ma.materialsId
ORDER BY m.Id DESC
```